# multifield form php issue

Tags: php, arrays, forms, field

I have a form that has 3 fields

textfield, checkbox, checkbox2

they are arrays by account number ie 
Returned[12345] 2nd[12345] 3rd[12345]

I need to pull the values and keys of them all but

if retuned has a value it stops there and puts that in the database. 
if returned is empty see 
if either checkbox is clicked 
if 3rd is and 2nd isnt say sorry 3 comes after 2
if 2nd is checked and 3rd isn't update that in database 
if 2nd and 3rd are checked update database

there are rows where nothing is filled in or checked at all

The code I have that ISN'T working is as follows:

```
    <?
if (isset($_POST["update"])) // if it's not set, do nothing.
{
include('cond.php');


$idx['Returned'] = array_keys( $_POST['Returned'] );
$idx['2nd'] = array_keys( $_POST['2nd'] );
$idx['3rd'] = array_keys( $_POST['3rd'] );

for(
     $i = 0;
     $i < min( array_map( 'count', $idx ) );
     $i++   )
    {
    $AN = $idx['Returned'][$i];
    $RET = $_POST['Returned'][$AN];
    $Chk = $idx['2nd'][$i];
    $Val = $_POST['2nd'][$Chk];
    $Chk2 = $idx['3rd'][$i];
    $Val2 = $_POST['3rd'][$Chk2];


//If date is filled in
if(!empty($RET)){

// store it
$doit = "UPDATE `dbname`.`tname` SET `Returned`= '$RET' WHERE `account_number`='$AN'";
mysql_query($doit) or die('mySQL Error: ' . mysql_error());

}else{

//                2nd isn't filled check 3rd
             if (empty($Val)) {

//        3rd is filled in 
               If(!empty($Val2)) {
            print "Third VOR cannot be checked before Second.";
               }else{
//              3rd is not set but 2nd is
                if(empty($Val2)){
                $doit = "UPDATE `dbname`.`tname` SET `Second`='$Val' WHERE `account_number`='$Chk'";
                mysql_query($doit) or die('mySQL Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }else{
//          2nd and 3rd are set
                $doit = "UPDATE `dbname`.`tname` SET `Second`='$Val' ,`Third`='$Val2' WHERE `account_number`='$Chk'";
                mysql_query($doit) or die('mySQL Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }//end if 2
               }//end if
             }//end if


   } 

}}
?>
```

Any ideas what or how to ensure I get my database updated and without the warning 
// example warning //
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/blah/public_html/blah/blah/insertret.php on line 9

lilRachie

Comment: Just in case my answer is not what you are looking for, what is the result of `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: where would i place that in that code?

Comment: at the top is fine, but post the results as well.

Comment: @jerone 'code'    $AN = $idx['Returned'][$i];
    $RET = $_POST['Returned'][$AN];
    $Chk = $idx['2nd'][$i];
    $Val = $_POST['2nd'][$Chk];
    $Chk2 = $idx['3rd'][$i];
    $Val2 = $_POST['3rd'][$Chk2];
'code' are the lines erroring with Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/blah/public_html/blah/blah/insertret.php on line whatever#

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have named your form-field as an array, like `name="returned[]"`, the values you receive are strings, not arrays.

So `$_POST['Returned']` would be a string that you need to parse to get the value you are looking for.

Comment: On my table yes they are Returned[12345] 2nd[12345] 3rd[12345] with the 12345 changing for each account number equaling a row.